Trading Bot - 'solders.transaction.Transaction' object has no attribute 'recent_blockhash' and no __dict__
I'm trying to get this Solana trading Python buy script to work, but I'm getting the following error. Any help would be highly appreciated.
Error:
Attempt 1 to create associated token account failed: 'solders.transaction.Transaction' object has no attribute 'recent_blockhash'  and no __dict__ for setting new attributes
Code:
                msg = Message([create_ata_ix], payer.pubkey())
                tx_ata = await client.send_transaction(
                    Transaction([payer], msg, (await client.get_latest_blockhash()).value.blockhash),
                    opts=TxOpts(skip_preflight=True,
                                preflight_commitment=Confirmed)
                )

Here's a link to the full code: https://github.com/chainstacklabs/pump-fun-bot/blob/main/learning-examples/manual_buy.py
Thanks in advance.
Tried to add the recent_blockhash to the Transaction and adjust the transaction creation process but got another error.
        # Construct the message and the transaction with the blockhash
        msg = Message([create_ata_ix], payer.pubkey())
        tx_ata = VersionedTransaction(
            payer=payer,
            message=msg,
            recent_blockhash=recent_blockhash  # Add the blockhash here
        )

        # Send the transaction
        tx_hash = await client.send_transaction(tx_ata, payer, opts=TxOpts(skip_preflight=True, preflight_commitment=Confirmed))

        await client.confirm_transaction(tx_hash.value, commitment="confirmed")

Got another error using this solution:
Attempt 1 to create associated token account failed: VersionedTransaction.__new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'payer'

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

You can find the VersionedTransaction and Message type declarations at https://github.com/kevinheavey/solders/blob/c857d3daa5f7d20ecdc38f6aaddbca65f32021c7/python/solders/transaction.pyi#L97 and https://github.com/kevinheavey/solders/blob/c857d3daa5f7d20ecdc38f6aaddbca65f32021c7/python/solders/message.pyi#L34, respectively.
Looking at those, you should probably use Message.new_with_blockhash and then pass the signers differently when creating the transaction. Try this:
        msg = Message.new_with_blockhash([create_ata_ix], payer.pubkey(), recent_blockhash)
        tx_ata = VersionedTransaction(
            message=msg,
            keypairs=[payer]
        )

